# Does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{p_ng_n}$ diverge?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

I know of Euler's proof that the sum of the reciprocals of the primes diverges. But what if we multiply the primes by it's following prime gap.
In other words, is  $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{p_ng_n} = \infty$$ true or false?

Comment: The average gap is $\log p$ by the Prime Number Theorem, I would ***guess*** that gaps are smaller than $2 \log p$ often enough to cause divergence.

Comment: See "Prime Gap" in Wikipedia.   I think the right answer is "Nobody knows."

Comment: The right answer is: by using the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we may get rid of the prime gaps, then by exploiting usual density arguments (summation by parts) we may prove the series *is* divergent.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1042649/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TRUE**: We may get rid of the prime gaps by using [Titu's lemma](https://brilliant.org/wiki/titus-lemma/).

We have:

$$ \frac{1}{p_n g_n}+\ldots+\frac{1}{p_N g_N}\geq \frac{\left(\sum_{k=n}^{N}\frac{1}{\sqrt{p_k}}\right)^2}{p_N-p_n}\tag{1}$$
hence if $N$ is around $n^2$ and $n$ is big enough, by partial summation the RHS of $(1)$ is roughly:
$$ 4\cdot\frac{p_N+p_n-2\sqrt{p_n p_N}}{(p_N-p_n)(\log N)^2} \tag{2}$$
so by combining $(2)$ with a condensation argument we easily get that the series $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{p_n g_n}$ is divergent.