# Does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{{p_n}^{g_n}}$ converge?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

Let $p_n$ be the $n^\text{th}$ prime and $g_n$ be the $n^\text{th}$ prime gap ($p_{n+1} - p_n$). Calculating the serie up to $n = 10^6$ it seems that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n}{{p_n}^{g_n}} < 1$$

Could this be true and is there a way to prove it?

(This is a follow up question to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1429997/does-sum-n-1-infty-frac1p-ng-n-diverge), although perhaps a harder nut to crack.)

Comment: How did you calculate the series up to $10^6$? Because on my machine the series up to $10^5$ took about 20 minutes to calculate

Comment: Sounds reasonable since the gap is soon $2$ or more and the $n$-th prime is greater than a constant times $n\log n$.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis I have a file with the first million primes and use JavaScript to go through it and do the calculations. Took about 8 seconds.

Comment: @Marijn So I guess you do it numerically? machine precision will make a lot of problems in such calculations ...

Comment: @DominicMichaelis You're right, it's by no means a perfect way.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis Machine precision is a much smaller issue than people think in such simple calculations. Floating point accuracy is $10^{-16}$ and if we assume random errors (sometimes adding and sometimes subtracting) it accumulates roughly as $\sqrt{N}10^{-16}$. The worst case is $N10^{-16}$. Both are really small for $N=10^6$ as here.

Comment: @Winther maybe I used the wrong word for it, I mean how many significant digits we have, because for example if the first time is surprisingly big (for example like 10^100) an the other terms are all 1, numerically the series should be constant 10^100 shouldnt it?

Comment: @DominicMichaelis I see. Yes, that is a valid point in general since $1.0+10^{-20} = 1.0$ If there were like $10^{20}$ numbers with size $10^{-20}$ that would indeed be a problem (one can partly get around this by summing smartly, i.e. adding smaller numbers in groups to get bigger number and add them).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $g_n\geq 2$ so $\frac{1}{p_n^{g_n}} \leq \frac{1}{p_n^2}$. Further we have $p_n> n\log n$ for $n\geq 1$ by the prime number theorem (or [Rosser's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosser's_theorem) to be precice). This implies that

$$S \leq \sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{n}{p_n^{g_n}} + \sum_{n=k}^\infty\frac{1}{n(\log n)^2} \leq \sum_{n=1}^{k}\frac{n}{p_n^{g_n}}  + \frac{1}{\log(k)}$$

since $ \sum_{n=k}^\infty\frac{1}{n(\log n)^2} \leq \int_k^\infty \frac{dx}{x\log^2(x)} = \frac{1}{\log(k)}$. Computing the first sum above numerically we get

$$S \leq 1.355$$

for $k=10$. To push the bound below $1$ seems to require more precise estimates.

Comment: Calculating with mathematica the first $10^5$ terms give 0.971055 as result, but with the $\frac{1}{\log(k)}$ bound even this isn't enough as $\log(10^5)=5\cdot \log(10)\approx 0.0868589$

Comment: @DominicMichaelis Yes one needs at least $10^{15}$ terms computed by the computer to be able to use these estimates to prove it. It seems unlikely that one is able to push the bound below $1$ without some really precise estimates.

Answer (score 5):

Note that $g_n\ge 2$ except at the beginning. Also, by Rosser's Theorem we have $p_n\gt n\log n$. Then the result follows by Comparison with the convergent series $\sum_2^\infty \frac{1}{n\log^2 n}$.  (One needs much less than Rosser's Theorem, the Prime Number Theorem is enough.)

Answer (score 1):

By Chebyshev's theorem (the weak version of the PNT) it follows that $p_n \geq C n \log n$ for some constant $C$ close to $1$, for any $n$ big enough. Since $g_n\geq 2$ for any $n\geq 2$ and the series 
$$\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{1}{n\log^2(n)}$$
is convergent by [Cauchy's condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test), your series is convergent, too.

Is the exact value of the original series really relevant for some purpose?

Comment: I'd be surprised if there was any relevance to knowing the exact value to which it converges, unless the value is exactly 1.

Comment: @Marijn: since in such a case... what?

Comment: Okay you're right, still no relevance... but it would be peculiar