# Does $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\left(\frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n}-1\right)^2 $ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

There appears to be a "prime constant" $\kappa$, generated from the sequence of primes:

$$\kappa = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\left(\frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n}-1\right)^2 \approx 1.653$$

Where $p_n$ is the nth prime.

However, how does one prove that such constant, does in fact, exist, that is, how does one prove that the above series converges?

Comment: Have you considered the asymptotic behaviour of $p_n$ as given by the prime number theorem? And its relative error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See my answer to the similar problem here: [Does this sum of prime numbers converge?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2325259/does-this-sum-of-prime-numbers-converge/2325765#2325765)

Note that $(\frac{p_{n+1}}{p_n}-1)^2 = \frac{(p_{n+1}-p_n)^2}{p_n^2}$.
Let $g_n=p_{n+1}-p_n$ be the sequence of prime gaps. Since $p_n\geq n$, the convergence would be proved if we have the convergence of
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{g_n^2}{n^2}.
$$
By this result of R. Heath-Brown: [Here](https://academic.oup.com/jlms/article-abstract/s2-20/2/177/899738/The-Differences-between-Consecutive-Primes-III?redirectedFrom=fulltext),
we have
$$
\sum_{n\leq x} g_n^2 \ll x^{\frac{23}{18}+\epsilon}.
$$
Applying the partial summation with $A(x)=\sum_{n\leq x}g_n^2$ and $f(x)=x^{-2}$, we obtain
$$
\sum_{n\leq x}\frac{g_n^2}{n^2}=\int_{1-}^x f(x)dA(x)
$$
$$
=A(x)f(x)-\int_{1-}^x A(t)f'(t)dt. \ \ (1)
$$
Since $3-(23/18) >1$, we obtain the convergence of (1). Hence, the desired sum converges by the comparison test.

Comment: I don't understand yet the proof, but I'm really thankful to know that it is convergent!